# Show Video with audio in VLC

Tags: python, vlc, libvlc

i have an Python Program that show photos and videos from a folder. The files in this folder a changing so a static playlist is not possible. I can create a playlist with a media_list_player

I create an instance with

```
instance = vlc.Instance('--input-repeat=-1 --aout=alsa --alsa-audio-device=plughw:0,0')
mediaList = instance.media_list_new()
mediaList.add_media(instance.media_new(tmpPath + "/start.jpg"))

list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
list_player.set_media_list(mediaList)
list_player.audio_set_volume(100)

list_player.play()
```

And i add new files with

```
mediaList.add_media(instance.media_new(showFile))
list_player.set_media_list(mediaList)
```

This works but when there is an video i dont have sound. "audio_set_volume()" dosen work. I tried the normal media_player but there i cant make a playlist. So i hope someone here can help me with adding sound to the vlc.

Comment: i get also the error whenm running the programm: [00007f82e0001e70] egl_x11 gl error: cannot select OpenGL API
but the program works

Comment: What happens when you use the command line? On the command line try: `vlc --input-repeat=-1 --aout=alsa --alsa-audio-device=plughw:0,0 somevideo.mp4`